# Index like layout with dates instead of page numbers

Tags: luatex, indexing

I am trying to improve upon this, which is just really horrible I think.  I want the sorted grouped index like layout, but it seems to be quite a fight to get rid of the page numbers which are kind of meaningless in this case, since I just want an index that gives the persons name, and a date associated with them in a kind of book of anniversaries.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{book}
\RequirePackage[a5paper,includehead,top=0.5in,inner=0.75in,outer=0.5in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}


\usepackage{imakeidx}

% this hides the commar
\begin{filecontents*}{necrology-book.ist}
delim_0 " "
delim_1 " "
delim_2 " "
\end{filecontents*}

\makeindex[name=persons,title={Table of Names in Alphabetical Order}, options=-s necrology-book]
\def\todayentrydate{}
\usepackage[]{idxlayout}

\newcommand*{\nop}[1]{} % this eats pages numbers

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\index}[2][]{
    \imki@wrindexentry{#1}{#2 \todayentrydate|nop}{0}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \def\todayentrydate{2000 May 19}

    \index[persons]{Member!Joe Blow}
    Joe Blow did a lot of nice stuff.

    \index[persons]{Boss!Jane Doe}
    Jane Doe was the boss.

    \printindex[persons]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an index and makeindex for this. Either build a bib and use biblatex or use glossaries.

Comment: Looked at them, seemed like they would be an even bigger fight to get what I want.

Comment: Found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341642/index-with-exercise-numbers which is I think is the answer I was looking for.